# My html input tags take arrays.Im not able to retrieve them from javascript

Tags: javascript

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Order</title>
```

The following calculates the total based on the checkboxes selected and gives a confirm box.displaying the total.No matter what this total shows as 0.

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
         function validate()
           {
              var x,y,i,j,p=0;
        j=parseInt(document.getElementById('loopcount').value);
              document.write(j);
        for (i=1;i<=j;i++)
        {
            document.write(i);
               if(document.getElementsByName('itemCode['+i+']').checked==true){
                x=parseFloat( document.getElementsByName('quantity['+i+']').value);
                document.write(x);
                y=parseFloat( document.getElementsByName('price['+i+']').value);
                document.write(y);
        p+=x*y;
                }
        }

    var conf=confirm("The total amount is:"+ p);

              if(conf==true){
                  header("Location:userHome.php");
              }
              else{
                  header("Location:orderveggies.php");
              }

        }


    </script>
    </head>
```

This code displays the data from mysql as checkboxes.My problem lies with the naming of the input tags which take arrays

```
    <body>
        <form name="myForm" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post" onsubmit="validate()">
        <table align="center" border="0">
            <tr>

                <th>item Code</th>
                <th>Vegetable</th>
                <th>Price/KG</th>
                <th>Quantity</th>
            </tr>


             <?php

             $db=  mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','ourveggies')
                            or die("Error!Could not connect to the database");
                    $query="select itemCode,itemName,price from veggies";
                    $result=mysqli_query($db,$query)
                            or die("Error in query".mysqli_error($db));
                    $count=mysqli_num_rows($result);
                    while($row= mysqli_fetch_array($result)){?>
                        <tr>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="itemCode[]" value="<?php echo $row['itemCode']; ?>"/><?php echo $row['itemCode']; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row['itemName']; ?></td>
                        <td><input type="hidden"  name="price[]" value="<?php echo $row['price']; ?>"/><?php echo $row['price']; ?></td>
                        <td><select name="quantity[]">
                                <option value="0.00">--Quantity--</option>
                                <option value="0.100">100 gm</option>
                                <option value="0.250">250 gm</option>
                                <option value="0.500">500 gm</option>
                                <option value="1">1 Kg</option>
                                <option value="2">2 Kg</option>
                                <option value="3">3 Kg</option>
                                <option value="4">4 Kg</option>
                                <option value="5">5 Kg</option>

                            </select></td>
                        </tr>

                  <?php  }?>
                    <input type="hidden" id="loopcount" name="loopcount" value="<?php echo $count; ?>"/>

            <tr>
                <td><input type="submit" name="order" value="order" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: please dont put // in front of normal english sentences that are obviously not a part of your code

Comment: Ok sorry will keep that in mind next time.

Answer (score 0):

```
name="itemCode[]"
```

**This means name="itemCode[]" and not name="itemCode[anything at all]"**

Try this:

```
<td><input 
        type="checkbox" 
        name="itemCode[<?php echo $row['itemCode']; ?>]"
        etc etc
</td>
```

also getElementsByName returns an array

Alternatively (using ids instead of name):

```
<td><input 
        type="checkbox" 
        id="itemCode[<?php echo $row['itemCode']; ?>]"
        etc etc
</td>
```

then in the javascript:

```
document.getElementById('itemCode['+i+']')
```

If you are still struggling to understand then use firebug or something similar in your browser to examine the outputted html. You have been giving all your inputs the same name

Comment: I have tried naming the input element itemCode[] and i tried using getElementById for retrieving.But Id has to be unique and I didnt know how to give an Id to the checkbox element while using arrays.Could you please help.Im new to programming

Comment: @user1744400: you really need to put something between the square brackets for it to work. I have included an example

Comment: <input type="checkbox" id="itemCode[<?php echo $row['itemCode']; ?>]" name="itemCode[]" value="<?php echo $row['itemCode']; ?>"/>if(document.getElementById('itemCode['+i+']').checked==true){

Comment: The loop is not going beyond 0.I have a statement document.write(i) in my code it just print 0.The above is the code i modified.

Comment: it's probably the output of docuemnt.write(j); that you are seeing. That for loop structure is correct, so that means that the bounding conditions are wrong. replace documnet.write(j) with document.write('j = '+j); and you will see what I mean.

Comment: So here's a lesson for you: If you generate messages for debugging purposes you should always make sure those messages have enough information to not confuse you if stuff goes wrong.

Answer (score 0):

document.getElementsByName() returns an array, not a single element.
try this: document.getElementsByName('itemCode[]')[i].checked.
and start your loop with 0!

```
for (i=0;i<j;i++)
{
    document.write(i);
    if(document.getElementsByName('itemCode[]')[i].checked==true){
        x=parseFloat( document.getElementsByName('quantity[]')[i].value);
        document.write(x);
        y=parseFloat( document.getElementsByName('price[]')[i].value);
        document.write(y);
        p+=x*y;
    }
}
```

Comment: it works if you use it correctly. what kind of error do you get anyway? Do you even have a javascript debugger?

Answer (score 0):

My answer was getting a little long winded so here is one with more detail on your actual problems: I have put comments next to the lines of code that I think are causing your confusion.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
     function validate()
       {
          var x,y,i,j,p=0;
          j=parseInt(document.getElementById('loopcount').value);
          document.write('j='+j);    // make your debugging messages more meaningful -S
    for (i=1;i<=j;i++)
    {
           document.write('i='+i);      // make your debugging messages more meaningful -S
           if(document.getElementsByName('itemCode['+i+']').checked==true)
           {
                //getElementsByName returns an array: replace them with getElementByName -S
                x=parseFloat( document.getElementByName('quantity['+i+']').value);
                document.write('x='+x);   // make your debugging messages more meaningful  
                y=parseFloat( document.getElementByName('price['+i+']').value);
                document.write('y='+y);   // make your debugging messages more meaningful
                p+=x*y;
            }
    }

var conf=confirm("The total amount is:"+ p);

          if(conf==true){
              header("Location:userHome.php");
          }
          else{
              header("Location:orderveggies.php");
          }

    }


</script>
</head>
```

Then for your PHP:

```
blah blah blah
while($row= mysqli_fetch_array($result)){?>
    <tr>
    <td>
         <input 
           type="checkbox" 
           name="itemCode[<?php echo $row['itemCode']; ?>]"  //Do this. seriously otherwise everything will have the same name -S
           value="<?php echo $row['itemCode']; ?>"/>
         <?php echo $row['itemCode']; ?>
    </td>
    <td>
         <?php echo $row['itemName']; ?>
    </td>
    <td>
         <input 
              type="hidden"  
              name="price[<?php echo $row['itemCode']; ?>]"  //Im assuming here you want to know what price belongs to what item -S
             value="<?php echo $row['price']; ?>"/>
         <?php echo $row['price']; ?>
    </td>

    etc etc
```

There are loads of bugs in your code. Please update your code to get rid of the problems I have pointed out, then we might be able to make some progress.